# InsertAlignmentTab() in Footer

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been attempting to add, using VBA, an alignment tab into the footer text - the line of code concerning this is as such

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(Selection.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Some text" & <ALIGNMENT TAB RIGHT> & "Some more text"
```

however, it appears that the InsertAlignmentTab() method can only be used when the insertion point is in the designated position. As I cannot move the insertion point into the footer, I cannot accomplish my goal.

My question is - is there a way to add an alignment tab to the footer without moving the insertion point there or is there a way to move the insertion point into the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this without moving the insertion point.

```
Sub AddAlignmentTabToFooter()
    Dim rngFooter As Range
    Set rngFooter = ActiveDocument.Sections(Selection.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    With rngFooter
        .Text = "Some more text"
        .Collapse wdCollapseStart
        .InsertAlignmentTab wdRight, wdMargin
        .InsertBefore "Some text"
    End With
    Set rngFooter = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do both, depending on what exactly it is you want to do.

To set the insertion point in the primary footer:

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekPrimaryFooter
```

To set it back to the main document:

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
```

Also, `InsertAlignmentTab` can be called on any Range object:

```
Selection.Range.InsertAlignmentTab wdRight, wdMargin
```

If you put it all together:

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekPrimaryFooter
Selection.Range.Text = "Some more text"
Selection.Range.InsertAlignmentTab wdRight, wdMargin
Selection.Range.Text = "Some text"
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
```

(Note that `Some text` and `Some more text` are reversed, because the `InsertAlignmentTab` command sends the current range to the right and afterwards the selection is still to the left, at least in my Word 2010 environment.)